# jUnit Check Hidden Files?

Tags: java, junit

I have an application that allow me to upload files using a addFile() method.

How should a jUnit test that check if a hidden file can be added look like?

I know that may look a bit stupid question, but I couldn't find any examples for this.

Comment: you have upload functionality.. means you have a html or jsp page. How are you planning to use Junit in your jsps?

Comment: Is not online upload, is something more like  total comander. I search for a file, I "upload" it but the file still remain on and only on my computer, is just that I'm monitorizing it with the application. The test (if my logic is correct) should be something like that: 1. check the hidden file's path. 2. return false if couldn't find it / return true if the file was found.

Comment: aah! so why can't we just make one file hidden in the windows explorer and test? You want to make a file hidden through Junit?

Comment: Well, that is exactly what I want to do. I created a folder on Desktop and created 2 files. One is hidden and another one is visible. The problem is that I have no clue how test it and to do it right. I couldn't find any examples with these kind of tests and I'm some kind newbie with jUnit..

Comment: I have tried to provide an answer. Please check and let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on the comments above.

Sample code snippet to test if the file is accessible (use your own logic here)

```
public class PathTest {

    public boolean pathAccessible(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        if (!file.isDirectory())
               file = file.getParentFile();
        return file.exists();

    }

}
```

Sample Junit test case (Assuming you have Junit setup properly)

```
public void test()
    {
        PathTest test = new PathTest();
        assertTrue(test.pathAccessible("regular file path"));
        assertFalse(test.pathAccessible("hidden file path"));

    }
```

Comment: That seems to make sense and I think I'm starting to understand how these jUnit test are working. Thank you a lot for your help!